# how to get response from function nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

```
const getLang = function (req) {
        translate.detect(req.body.phrase, function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        });


router.post('/addPhrases', (req, res) => {
    var lang = getLang(req);
    console.log(lang);
})
```

console.log(lang) from second function print undefined, it runs before the first function make a return

how can I fix it?

Comment: `translate.detect` is asynchronous. You have to `console.log` inside it's callback. `var lang = getLang(req)` will not wait and give you back the language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Promises allow you to wait for async tasks to complete, using ".then" and ".catch". The ".then" is called when the Promise successfully resolves. The ".catch" is called when the Promise is rejected.

For your example you can instead do:

```
const getLang = function (req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        translate.detect(req.body.phrase, (err, res) => {
            if (err){
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log(res);
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
}


router.post('/addPhrases', (req, res) => {
    var lang = getLang(req).then((lang) => {
        console.log(lang);
    }).catch((error) => {
        // handle error here
        throw new Error(error);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is found in the fact that your `getLang` function doesn’t actually return anything, and so the default return value is going to be `undefined`. Even still, you correctly point out that `getLang` makes an asynchronous function call, so even if you return the value of your translation function from `getLang`, this will not allow you to successfully assign your variable to it unless you:

1. wrap `getLang` in a promise and use async/await, or
2. just make use of the translation value inside the callback function of `translate.detect`